# Incorrect dependency added to CMake target "by magic", variable_watch reports no write

Tags: cmake

**Repro:** Checkout [this repo](https://github.com/mcclure/lovr), branch ZP_midi, commit 4c82565. `git submodule update --init` and then `(mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..)`.
**Expected:** This builds a CMake project with many `include_subdirectory` subprojects, each of which build a helper library.
**Observed:** Two of the subprojects are interfering with each other. When I run the normal debug tools, they produce answers that make no sense (a library appears to have been created, at the moment of `add_library`, already having a dependency on the other project).

When I run the cmake configure, I get

```
-- Compiling with support for: 
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "RtMidiTargets" ...) includes target "rtmidi_static" which requires target "libluajit" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error in deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt:
  export called with target "rtmidi_static" which requires target "libluajit"
  that is not in any export set.
```

The target rtmidi_static comes out of the CMakeLists `deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt`. The target libluajit comes out of `deps/luajit/CMakeLists.txt`. They are completely unrelated; neither should depend on the other.

If I look in `build/CMakeCache.txt`, I see:

```
//Dependencies for the target
rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;libluajit;general;-framework CoreServices;general;-framework CoreAudio;general;-framework CoreMIDI;general;-framework CoreFoundation;
```

So, the error message is correct; rtmidi_static depends on libluaijt. But why? **This is where it gets weird.**

I add `variable_watch(rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS)` to the start of `CMakeLists.txt`. Then I run `(cd build && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. --trace)`. My hope is this will allow me to see when the dependency is added to rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS.

At the moment the rtmidi_static target is created in `deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt`, I get this trace spew:

```
 /Users/mcc/work/gh/lovr/deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt(166):  add_library(rtmidi_static STATIC ${rtmidi_SOURCES} )
CMake Debug Log at deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt:166 (add_library):
  Variable "rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS" was accessed using UNKNOWN_READ_ACCESS
  with value "".


/Users/mcc/work/gh/lovr/deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt(167):  list(APPEND RTMIDI_LIB_TARGETS rtmidi_static )
/Users/mcc/work/gh/lovr/deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt(170):  set_target_properties(rtmidi_static PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER RtMidi.h SOVERSION ${SO_VER} VERSION ${FULL_VER} )
/Users/mcc/work/gh/lovr/deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt(175):  target_include_directories(rtmidi_static PRIVATE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${RTMIDI_DIR}> $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}> ${RTMIDI_INCDIRS} )
/Users/mcc/work/gh/lovr/deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt(181):  target_compile_definitions(rtmidi_static PRIVATE ${RTMIDI_API_DEFS} )
/Users/mcc/work/gh/lovr/deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt(182):  target_link_libraries(rtmidi_static ${RTMIDI_LINKLIBS} )
CMake Debug Log at deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt:182 (target_link_libraries):
  Variable "rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS" was accessed using READ_ACCESS with
  value "general;libluajit;".


CMake Debug Log at deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt:182 (target_link_libraries):
  Variable "rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS" was accessed using READ_ACCESS with
  value "general;libluajit;general;-framework CoreServices;".


CMake Debug Log at deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt:182 (target_link_libraries):
  Variable "rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS" was accessed using READ_ACCESS with
  value "general;libluajit;general;-framework CoreServices;general;-framework
  CoreAudio;".


CMake Debug Log at deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt:182 (target_link_libraries):
  Variable "rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS" was accessed using READ_ACCESS with
  value "general;libluajit;general;-framework CoreServices;general;-framework
  CoreAudio;general;-framework CoreMIDI;".
```

So somehow, in those five lines, "general;libluajit" is getting added, but in a way that `variable_watch` cannot see.

**To make things even more confusing**, say I try to use message() to tease out when those lines are being added. I modify `deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt` so that the `add_library` line has `message()`s before and after it:

```
message("zzzz1 RTMIDI_LINKLIBS (${RTMIDI_LINKLIBS}) rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS (${rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS})")
  add_library(rtmidi_static STATIC ${rtmidi_SOURCES})
message("zzzz2 RTMIDI_LINKLIBS (${RTMIDI_LINKLIBS}) rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS (${rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS})")
```

This prints

```
/Users/mcc/work/gh/lovr/deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt(166):  message(zzzz1 RTMIDI_LINKLIBS (${RTMIDI_LINKLIBS}) rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS (${rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS}) )
CMake Debug Log at deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt:166 (message):
  Variable "rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS" was accessed using UNKNOWN_READ_ACCESS
  with value "".


zzzz1 RTMIDI_LINKLIBS (-framework CoreServices;-framework CoreAudio;-framework CoreMIDI;-framework CoreFoundation) rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS ()
/Users/mcc/work/gh/lovr/deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt(167):  add_library(rtmidi_static STATIC ${rtmidi_SOURCES} )
CMake Debug Log at deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt:167 (add_library):
  Variable "rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS" was accessed using UNKNOWN_READ_ACCESS
  with value "".


/Users/mcc/work/gh/lovr/deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt(168):  message(zzzz2 RTMIDI_LINKLIBS (${RTMIDI_LINKLIBS}) rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS (${rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS}) )
CMake Debug Log at deps/rtmidi_build/CMakeLists.txt:168 (message):
  Variable "rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS" was accessed using READ_ACCESS with
  value "general;libluajit;".


zzzz2 RTMIDI_LINKLIBS (-framework CoreServices;-framework CoreAudio;-framework CoreMIDI;-framework CoreFoundation) rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS (general;libluajit;)
```

Notice on the line before `add_library` that `rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS` is empty and on the line after it contains `general;libluajit;`.

**My question:** What is happening? Why? How do I make it not happen?
And is it a bug that `add_library` is appending `general;libluajit;` to the LIB_DEPENDS without the `variable_watch` triggering? Should I file this?

EDIT: I just realized I never mentioned my CMake version. I'm running these tests with CMake 3.20.0 on MacOS 10.13.6.

Comment: Looks like your variable `rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS` conflicts with "automatic" CACHE variable `<target>_LIB_DEPENDS` which is created by old CMake versions. See e.g. [that bugreport](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16364).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I don't have a variable `rtmidi_static_LIB_DEPENDS`. I am printing out, and using variable_watch on, the "automatic" variable. I am doing this because I do not know of a better way to track the dependencies of a target and when/why those dependencies are added. (If there is a better way I'd love to know.)

Comment: Probably, before calling `add_library` you have called `link_libraries`, like in this line: [CMakeLists.txt#L361](https://github.com/mcclure/lovr/blob/28781c5dcdb0c68384f27ac2e800c90cd105c927/CMakeLists.txt#L361). This would explain why your library get linked libraries at the time of creation. As for `variable_watch`, I wouldn't expect it to work in case of "internal" variables.

Comment: Ahh, @Tsyvarev, this fixed my problem exactly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This comment is the answer to the question. One of the CMakeLists contained `link_libraries`, which adds a link dependency to every target created after that point in CMakeLists configure-step execution. [Incorrect dependency added to CMake target "by magic", variable_watch reports no write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67551482/incorrect-dependency-added-to-cmake-target-by-magic-variable-watch-reports-no?noredirect=1#comment119404663_67551482)